# Possible to copy files and directory structure but don't copy file contents (i.e. 0 byte file size)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer, xcopy

I'm wondering if it's possible to copy files and directory structure, but don't actually copy file contents. I want to copy over file names and extensions but have each individual file be 0 bytes in size. From what I've read, it looks like Xcopy might be able to handle this, but that it might not copy files.

I'm open to all suggestions, but I'd prefer an included Windows utility if possible.

Comment: [robocopy](http://ss64.com/nt/robocopy.html) with `/CREATE` switch: create directory tree structure + zero-length files only.

Comment: `robocopy [SOURCE] [TARGET] /mir /create` works for me.

Comment: @wiktor that is an excellent answer,  it works, you should post that as an answer. i'll upvote it

Answer (score 1):

`robocopy [SOURCE] [TARGET] /mir /create` works for me.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a [walkthrough](http://cects.com/copying-directory-structures-without-files/), it covers Xcopy, Robocopy (command line) and some other tools with GUI

Comment: No it does not. Your link says excluding files.  But he wants file just 0 byte versions

Comment: Even if the walkthrough solved the problem, the answer itself would still be low quality, because it's a link-only answer.